# VAE reconstruction vs generation

Tags: neural-networks, variational-bayes

I have been reading theory on VAE and trying to understand the loss function. The loss function is made up of Reconstruction loss and KL divergence term.  What happens when you have  good generated images but poor reconstructions? Is it due to high reconstruction loss but low KL divergence loss?